# Log function name of each function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to log name of each function on console when control enters that function without explicitly adding console.log in each function? I am new to JavaScript and to this project. It would help me greatly to debug the code and understand the flow of application.

In my application other developers have subscribed to events at multiple places and its hard for me to follow the flow.

Comment: Try using a debugger; these days most browers (e.g. Chrome and Firefox) come with one built-in.

Comment: You can also set up Editors such as WebStorm and Visual Studio Code to watch your application and pause at breakpoints etc.

Comment: @gyre: I am not seeking help on how to debug or set debug points. I am just interested to know which all functions were called during a flow. This becomes tricky when you have subscribed to events across multiple files.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I can, but for that I need to be be aware which functions will get called. Most of the cases i know the flow but having function name of console will help in a big way.

Comment: Have you tried `console.trace()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace